# NTFS MFT datarun

Tags: filesystems, ntfs, ntfs-mft

I am trying to parse a Data Run in an MFT Record and I'm comparing my results to Active Disk Editor. The data run is as follows:

.... **4**2 0F 01 **FD 83 90 *D9*** 0C (second attribute starts here)

If I understand correctly: this is how it should be parsed:

- number of bytes to parse the cluster count: 2
- number of bytes to parse cluster location: 4
- Parse cluster count: 0F 01   (in little endian)  => 271
- Parse first cluster location:  0x**D99083FD**  =>   3,650,126,845
- Expecting a 00 instead of 0C to mark the end of the cluster

However, in active disk editor:

- the cluster location is: 9,470,973 which is **0x 9083FD**.  ( ***the D9 is ignored***). It turns out that this location is the correct one.
- If I try to change the number of bytes representing the cluster location (the **4** in **4**2), here is what happens:

  - If I change it to 4 or 5, the cluster location remains the same (9470973)
  - If I change it to 3, the cluster location becomes negative
  - No value change on D9 0C seems to affect the outcome

Can anyone let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some additional research, I accidentally read about NTFS fixups. For those that might encounter the same issue in the future, the idea is as follows:

- Update Sequence Number (USN) is a 2-byte entity that overwrites the last two **bytes** in each used sector. It is done for verification purposes.
- Update Sequence Array (USA) contains the array of overwritten 2-bytes at the end of each sector.

Reading the structure without accounting for USN and USA is problematic. It can mess up file names, data runs, etc. I encountered this info on:
https://www.taksati.org/ntfs-fix-ups/

Long story short, when I accounted for this difference, the first cluster location became:

```
0x009083FD
```

Since the data run list info became: `42 0F 01 FD 83 90 00 00`.

Answer (score 2):

There is a little problem in your comment:
overwrites the last two **sectors** in each used sector
the sectors should be bytes.

It is a general problem for new guy of NTFS.
All records(index/FR/RCRC) must be read after USN handled.